# Difference between rdf:List and co:List

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

Both RDF and the Collections Ontology define a list with a head tail structure. When would one use which one?

- [rdf:List](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_list)
- [co:List](http://150.146.207.114/lode/extract?url=http://purl.org/co#d4e483)

Answer (score 2):

The Collections Ontology is described in detail in this article in the SWJ: [The Collections Ontology:creating and handling collections in OWL 2 DL frameworks](http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/system/files/swj506.pdf). From a cursory glance at its abstract and introduction, the main motivation for it as an alternative to RDF Collections is that the latter can not easily be used in OWL *DL*, specifically.